# How to get the parameters in $_GET url via ajax or any http request?

Tags: php, ajax

For example i have this form that i send to queries.php.

```
echo "<form method='GET' action='queries.php'>
       <label>name1</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name1'/>
       <label>name2</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name2'/>
       <label>name3</label>
       <input type='checkbox' name='name3'/>
       <input type='submit' name='sendData' value='Send'/>
      </form>";
```

In order to perform an ajax call the url can be `queries.php?name1=on&name2=on&name3=on&SendData=Send` or with less and variable parameters.

If i have main.js how can i access the url if the parameters i send are variables? For variables i mean that they are not always the same.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "queries/queries.php?",
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);

}).fail(function (response) {
  console.log(response);

});
```

}

Hope i've been clear, thank you. And sorry if the question can be newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to get the data from the form fields and put it into the URL?

If so, the simplest way is to handle the form's submit event, and then have jQuery serialise the form's data for you, and send it to the server in your AJAX request.

For example:

HTML (note the ID on the form):

```
<form method='GET' id="someForm" action='queries.php'>
   <label>name1</label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='name1'/>
   <label>name2</label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='name2'/>
   <label>name3</label>
   <input type='checkbox' name='name3'/>
   <input type='submit' name='sendData' value='Send'/>
</form>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(function() { //wait till page has loaded
  $("#someForm").submit(function(event) { //add "submit" event handler to the form
    event.preventDefault(); //stop normal postback behaviour
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "queries/queries.php?",
      data: $(this).serialize() //grab the form data
      dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

`serialize()` will output a querystring (like you showed in your question) automatically and, for a GET request, append it to the URL - although for a form like this, it's usually preferable to use POST to submit, but that's up to you. Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Thank you again i think you centered the point again. How can you understand me so well? Haha I'm still a junior figure so i can lack of explanation.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I guess I just read the question carefully, and maybe guessed a little bit what you probably wanted, because this situation is quite common and I have implemented the same type of thing a lot of times before.

Answer (score 0):

Use data property of JQuery AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "queries/queries.php?",
data: {name1: variable1, name2: variable2, name3: variable3},
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Where variable1, variable2, variable3 are variables and name1, name2, name3 are GET variables.
So in PHP you'll receive them $name1 = $_GET["name1"];

If you have html form and want to submit entire form using AJAX, go for @ADyson's approach as it'll submit entire form and easier to write and cleaner too.

Comment: Thank you i will take in mind this method too

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` needs to be removed from this.